# What is the correct way to say "Why did the guy with pink camera eat my food?"

Tags: grammar, particles

> ピンクのカメラの人はなぜ自分の飯を食ってしまったのか
>
> ピンクのカメラが人はなぜ自分の飯を食ってしまったのか

Which particle should be used before 人, の or が ?

Please explain the answer

Comment: By ピンクのカメラの人, do you mean "a person holding a pink camera"?

Comment: I  want say a person with a pink camera, which one will be correct ピンクのカメラの人 or ピンクのカメラが人  don't we use の  particle to show possession ?  
so will  ピンクのカメラの人 mean camera's person ?

Answer (score 2):

ピンクのカメラ**が**人 is clearly ungrammatical, at least in modern Japanese. It must be ピンクのカメラ**の**人. It is parsed in an embedded structure like this.

> ［［ピンク**の**カメラ］**の**人］

The particle の is used to express various types of relationship, including but not limited to possession. The first の is used to modify the thing referenced (カメラ) with one of its attributes, namely color. The second refers to a situation where the person referenced is holding a pink camera. It would correspond to “with” in English.

It is important to note that の works within a noun phrase, whereas が plays a particular function on the sentence (or clause) level.

By the way, 自分の飯 may be understood as referring to the food of the person holding a pink camera, instead of the speaker’s ("my food").

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has already explained the が・の thing, so I'd like to clear up some of the other issues with your translation.

> ピンクのカメラの人はなぜ自分の飯を食ってしまったのか

sounds a little off. More natural, I think, would be:

> ピンクのカメラの人はなぜ（私・僕・俺）のご飯を食べてしまったのかな

自分, as the other answerer said, could easily be taken to refer to 「ピンクのカメラの人」, and 飯 and 食う can sound somewhat crude. A bare ～のか at the end of a sentence containing a question word makes it seem like an incomplete sentence containing an embedded question (like 「なぜ食べたのか、わからない」 'I don't know *why he ate it*').